# JSON Schema Validation $ref outer documents

Tags: json, jsonschema

Im using org.everit.json.schema for json schema validation in a spring boot application.

I have the following schema, that references a json schema on the same directory. The directory is the resources directory.. and am using everit to load it.

When i do this i get the following exception

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: dataset.json
```

it seems everit cannot find the other document.. how can i get the validator to pull in other documents..

example of what im doing..

main.json

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "test.json",
  "title": "test",
  "type": "object",
  "description": "test.",
  "properties": {
    "data": {"$ref": "dataset.json"}
   }
}
```

dataset.json

```
{
  "type": "string",
  "description": "The data ",
  "enum": ["string", "integer"]
}
```

Comment: I also tried this example with newtonSoft Json validator, and it throws string index out of bounds with a warning  "Could not load validator $ref"..

Answer (score 0):

self referencing documents can be done by using ref: '[hash]'

also newtonSoft uses recursion well.'